# Why `make logs` does not run command?

Tags: makefile

I have next `Makefile`:

```
logs:
    sudo docker logs -f maitre_d_backend
```

When I do `make logs` I get ``` make: ``logs' is up to date. ```

But if I change in `Makefile` target from `logs` to `log` then `make log` works as expected.

What is wrong with `logs` target?

Comment: Nothing is wrong. `logs` is already up to date, apparently. What did you expect `make` to do?

Comment: @melpomene: Which `logs` are up to date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This message means you have a file or directory named `logs` that already exists.  When make looks at a target that has no prerequisites (as the `logs` target does not) then the target is considered up to date if that file (or directory) exists, and it's considered out of date if that file (or directory) does not exist.

If you are trying to use `logs` as an internal special target name and don't want to tie it to an actual file (or directory) on the disk, then you should declare it [to be phony](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html):

```
.PHONY: logs
logs:
        ...
```